# Unable to Run Automated Test Cases With Minimized Window in Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber

I use Cucumber framework in version 4.0 and Selenium Server Standalone in version 2.53.0 to automate test cases. While Google Chrome version is 86.0.4240, the already automated test cases are executed without any problems and even when the Web explorer window is minimized each step is executed perfectly.

However when the Chrome version is updated to the latest available version, these test cases execution is stopped when the Web explorer window is minimized.

Does any body know how to avoid this happening after updating the Web Explorer?

Thank you!